# Android: how to manage my app when it comes in background

Tags: android, background

I have this problem: my app android has a problems when it comes in background. When I press back it closes but when I re-click on it it doesn't work (button doesn't working) and when I close my app using home or an other app, if I re-click on it, it works but if I don't use it, after a little time it has been forced to stop. Why? How can I manage this problem? Thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) and then implement methods based on your needs.

For example:

```
onPause() {
   //Stop your services
}

onResume() {
   //Restart your services
}
```